# problems with my website slideshow

Tags: html, css, resize, slideshow

i'm building this website for a wine company and in this particular page i have a problem with the slideshow

as you can see on the link http://achavalferrer.com/test/productos-finca-mirador the slideshow work perfectly but when i resize the browser it breaks, the images is too big for the screen, but, if you keep decreasing the browser it suddenly fits so it looks good on medium size devices but keeps screwing on large ones, i don't know what's going on but i need to fix this ASAP...

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce you in using the slick.js plugin for fully responsive Slideshows. It works very well and i think you can avoid your problem with it.

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/